# How to write a dynamic query inside @Query annotation for spring mongo JPA

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to write a query for spring mongo's @Query annotation, where it gets data for all those fields whose value is not null, that's coming from the front end.

Currently, I have tried this, but it just returns all the records.

```
@Query("{ { $or: [ { $where: '?0 == null' }, { name: '?0' } ] }" +
        " { $or: [ { $where: '?1 == null' }, { age: '?1' } ] }" +
        " { $or: [ { $where: '?2 == null' }, { batch: '?2' } ] }" +
        " { $or: [ { $where: '?3 == null' }, { $or: [{startDate: '?3'}, {endDate: '?3'}] } ] } }")
```

Edit: I have tried wrapping the $or inside an $and , but it still returns all the records.

```
@Query("{$and:{\r\n"
        + "   { $or: [ { $where: '?0 == null' }, { name: '?0' } ] },\r\n"
        + "   { $or: [ { $where: '?1 == null' }, { age: '?1' } ] },\r\n"
        + "   { $or: [ { $where: '?2 == null' }, { batch: '?2' } ] },\r\n"
        + "}}")
```

Edit:
tried criteria builder , now it says cannot find "find()" method
[image]

Comment: arent you missing an "and" block that wraps all the "or" blocks?

Comment: yeah , i tried that approach also , still no luck , i have updated my post for reference.

Comment: Should all the params be `?0` in the second example? Shouldn't they be `?0`, `?1` and so on?

Comment: Also, you might consider using `CriteriaBuilder`, because this kind of usecase is exactly what it's meant for. https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

Comment: @Tarmo yeah correct , it's ?0 , ?1 like that only

Comment: @Tarmo, so writing this inside a Query annotation is not the correct approach?

Comment: I am not saying it can't be done like that. I'm saying that for cases when the criteria is complex and very dynamic and depends highly on the input, CriteriaBuilder is the tool to use. The code will be more readable and better maintainable than a hackish multiline escaped string.

Comment: @Tarmo I tried using CriteriaBuilder, but now it says cannot find "find()" method , I have edited the post and attached the screenshot. Currently i am extending MongoRepository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250372/discussion-between-tarmo-and-confused-geek).